# Error: HWCREP0011E: Failed to connect to the repository database. Connection authorization failure occurred. Reason: Security mechanism not supported

Tags: cloud, db2-luw

I am connecting to Lite plan Db2 on Cloud from IBM data server manager.

I have created a free instance on db2 on cloud but i could not establish the connection from IBM 
data server manager tool.

**I am facing the following error** while testing the connection.

Error:

HWCREP0011E: Failed to connect to the repository database. Connection authorization failure occurred. Reason: Security mechanism not supported.

Can you please help me to resolve this error.

Thanks for reading my post. Thanks a lot.

Thanks
Sridhar

Comment: Add details. Where did you add the connection information? Are you connecting via userid / password or auth token or API key?

Comment: I have filled the hostname,DB name, port number, JDBC string, user name( I have selected user name only connect mechanism) in IBM db2 data management console to configure the repository and connection information.

Comment: I am trying to make a connection to db2 on cloud from DB2 data server manager client.